# Conexão ao banco de dados - MySQL e Java

Tags: java, mysql

Já tenho um servidor local em minha máquina (localhost) com o MySQL funcionando normalmente. A partir daí, gostaria de conectar meu banco de dados com o Java, mas... como eu faço isso? Existe algum componente do Swing que exiba os campos de uma determinada tabela do MySQL?

Estou criando um programa para o desktop de meu parceiro. Ou seja, é outro PC! O banco de dados, mesmo assim, conecta-se? É preciso internet?

Comment: Existe sim, o mais utilizado é o jTable, onde os dados são carregados em uma tabela

Comment: Se o seu amigo quiser conectar no banco de dados que fica na sua maquina acho que a melhor forma é voce criar um ip fixo e configurar a conexão com esse ip

Comment: Valeu! Mas... você poderia me dar um código de exemplo?

Comment: No site do Netbeans tem um breve tutorial ensinando a fazer isso. Tente estuda-lo e faze-lo, caso tenha alguma outra dúvida referente a algum ponto mais específico do tutorial, poste para que possamos ajuda-lo: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql_pt_BR.html

Comment: estou fazendo uma explicação, só um momento

Answer (score 16):

Vou tentar dar uma resumida de como começar uma aplicação com banco de dados usando JDBC:
O primeiro passo é criar a classe conexão, podemos cria-la da seguinte forma:

```
public class Conexao {

    private static final String USUARIO = "root";
    private static final String SENHA = "";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/meubanco";
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    // Conectar ao banco
    public static Connection abrir() throws Exception {
        // Registrar o driver
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        // Capturar a conexão
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
        // Retorna a conexao aberta
        return conn;


    }

}
```

O método anterior retorna a conexão aberta, lembrando que é preciso adicionar o Connector/J que é o driver responsável por conectar o java ao Mysql, voce pode baixar o driver nesse [LINK](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Após baixa-lo vá no seu projeto, clique na pasta Bibliotecas/Adicionar JAR... Procure o seu driver e clique em adicionar, isso no Netbeans. Se estiver utilizando o Eclipse Clique no seu projeto e vá em Build Path/Configure Build Path e em seguida procure pela guia Libraries, clique na opção Add External Jars e selecione o Driver.

---

2ª Parte:
Vou tentar simplificar ao maximo essa explicação para que não fique muito extensa, caberá a voce estudar mais sobre o assunto depois.
Vamos começar com a Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente {

    private Integer codigoCliente;
    private String nomeCliente;
    private Integer idadeCliente;

    public Integer getCodigoCliente() {
        return codigoCliente;
    }

    public void setCodigoCliente(Integer codigoCliente) {
        this.codigoCliente = codigoCliente;
    }

    public String getNomeCliente() {
        return nomeCliente;
    }

    public void setNomeCliente(String nomeCliente) {
        this.nomeCliente = nomeCliente;
    }

    public Integer getIdadeCliente() {
        return idadeCliente;
    }

    public void setIdadeCliente(Integer idadeCliente) {
        this.idadeCliente = idadeCliente;
    }

}
```

Agora é necessário uma classe que interaja com o Banco de Dados, geralmente essa classe tem atribuído o nome `DAO` que faz parte do padrão DAO ([Data Access Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113840/como-funciona-o-padr%C3%A3o-dao))
Presumindo que voce já tem informações salvas no banco e quer apenas retorna-las em uma tabela vou apenas fazer o método que faz a pesquisa desses dados:

```
public class ClienteDAO {

    public List<Cliente> buscar(Cliente c) throws Exception {
        /* Define a SQL */
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT cod_cliente, nome_cliente, idade_cliente ");
        sql.append("FROM tabela_cliente ");
        sql.append("WHERE nome_cliente LIKE ? ");
        sql.append("ORDER BY nome_cliente ");

        /* Abre a conexão que criamos o retorno é armazenado na variavel conn */
        Connection conn = Conexao.abrir();

        /* Mapeamento objeto relacional */
        PreparedStatement comando = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        comando.setString(1, "%" + c.getNomeCliente()+ "%");

        /* Executa a SQL e captura o resultado da consulta */
        ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

        /* Cria uma lista para armazenar o resultado da consulta */
        List<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

        /* Percorre o resultado armazenando os valores em uma lista */
        while (resultado.next()) {
            /* Cria um objeto para armazenar uma linha da consulta */
            Cliente linha = new Cliente();
            linha.setCodigoCliente(resultado.getInt("cod_cliente"));
            linha.setNomeCliente(resultado.getString("nome_cliente"));
            linha.setIdadeCliente(resultado.getInt("idade_cliente"));
            /* Armazena a linha lida em uma lista */
            lista.add(linha);
        }

        /* Fecha a conexão */
        resultado.close();
        comando.close();
        conn.close();

        /* Retorna a lista contendo o resultado da consulta */
        return lista;
    }

    }
```

---

3ª Parte:
Pronto temos o DAO(ClienteDAO) e o MODEL(Cliente) agora na sua view(Tela) vo adiciona um `Painel de Rolagem` e dentro desse painel voce coloca uma `Tabela` ficando de tal forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida voce clica com o botão direito na sua tabela, vá em propriedades, procure por Model clique nos `...` e `Definir Propriedades...` selecione `Código Personalizado` e digite o seguinte código: new ClienteTableModel() e ignore o erro, pois iremos resolver no próximo passo. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

4º Passo (Ultimo)
Precisamos de mais uma Classe, essa classe é a mesma que instanciámos em nossa `JTable` logo acima.

```
public class ClienteTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    /* Lista para armazenar os cabeçalhos da tabela */

    private Vector colunas;

    /* Lista para armazenar os dados da tabela */
    private Vector linhas;

    public ClienteTableModel() {
        /* Definição das colunas da tabela */
        colunas = new Vector();
        colunas.add("Código");
        colunas.add("Nome");
        colunas.add("Idade");

        /* Definição dos dados da tabela */
        linhas = new Vector();
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        /* Captura o total de linhas da tabela */
        int totalLinhas = linhas.size();

        /* Retorna o total de linhas */
        return totalLinhas;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        /* Captura o total de colunas da tabela */
        int totalColunas = colunas.size();

        /* Retorna o total de colunas */
        return totalColunas;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int coluna) {
        /* Captura o nome da coluna */
        String nomeColuna = (String) colunas.get(coluna);

        /* Retorna o nome da coluna */
        return nomeColuna;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
        /* Captura o registro informado */
        Vector registro = (Vector) linhas.get(linha);

        /* Dentro do registro captura a coluna selecionada */
        Object dado = registro.get(coluna);

        /* Retorna o valor capturado */
        return dado;
    }

    public void adicionar(List<Cliente> lista) {
        /* Reinicializa os dados da tabela */
        linhas = new Vector();

        /* Percorre a lista copiando os dados para a tabela */
        for (Cliente d : lista) {
            Funcionario f = new Funcionario();
            /* Cria uma linha da tabela */
            Vector<Object> linha = new Vector();
            linha.add(d.getCodigoCliente());
            linha.add(d.getNomeCliente());
            linha.add(d.getIdadeCliente());
            /* Adiciona a linha a tabela */
            linhas.add(linha);
        }
        /* Atualiza a tabela */
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

}
```

Esse código é responsável por preencher a tabela, mas ainda falta um detalhe. Como atualizar a tabela, ou seja, como carregar os dados. Eu faço da seguinte forma:
no começo do código da sua tela, após o construtor adicione um metodo chamado atualizar da seguinte forma:

```
  public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
```

Após o construtor adicionar:

```
public void atualizar(){
         try{
             /* Criação do modelo */
            Cliente d = new Cliente();

            /* Criação do DAO */
            ClienteDAO dao = new ClienteDAO();
            List<Cliente> lista = dao.buscar(d);

            /* Captura o modelo da tabela */
            ClienteTableModel modelo = (ClienteTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

            /* Copia os dados da consulta para a tabela */
            modelo.adicionar(lista);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao tentar buscar um Cliente");
        }
    }
```

E em seguida, clique na sua `tela(jFrame)` e adicione um evento `Window/WindowOpened` e dentro desse evento faça o seguinte:

```
  private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

        atualizar();

        //Opcional
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

    }
```

E pronto, sua aplicação está pronta para carregar os dados do banco em uma tabela. Me desculpe se a explicação não foi muito boa, ou se ficou muito extensa, acho que não tenho muito o "dom" de explicar. Boa sorte com os códigos e estude bastante.

Comment: Estou tendo problemas com esta linha do código: public List<Funcionario> buscar(Funcionario f) throws Exception: a IDE diz: type List does not  take paramenters

Comment: @alexjosesilva veja se você fez o import da Lista corretamente. `Java.util.list`

Comment: Fiz tudo como esta aqui escrito...porém o erro continua