# Erro na conexão com o banco. Java + Workbench

Tags: java, mysql

Erro na conexão com o banco. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
package conexaoprojeto;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexaoProjeto {

    private final String Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String Url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ConexaoProjeto";
    private final String User = "root";
    private final String Pass = "123456";
    public Connection conn;
    public Statement stmt;
    public ResultSet rs;


    public Statement Conectar() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", Driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Url, User, Pass);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com Sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu uma falha! Não pode ser conectado" + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return stmt;
    }

    public void Desconectar() {
        try {
            conn.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexão fechada com sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexão falhou ao ser encerrada!" + "\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você adicionou o .jar do driver mysql no seu projeto?

Comment: [Relacionado 1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63778/conex%C3%A3o-ao-banco-de-dados-mysql-e-java?rq=1) [Relacionado 2](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql_pt_BR.html)

Answer (score 1):

Experimente fazer assim:

```
package conexaoprojeto;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Conecta {

    private String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String BD = "ConexaoProjeto";
    private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" +BD;
    private String USERNAME = "root";
    private String PASSWORD = "123456";
    private Connection conexao;
    private Statement stm;
    private String msg;

    public Conecta() {
        this.msg = this.iniciaConexao();                
    }

    public Conecta(String bd, String user, String senha) {
        this.BD = bd;
        this.USERNAME = user;
        this.PASSWORD = senha;
        this.msg = this.iniciaConexao();
    }

    public String iniciaConexao() {
        try {
            Class.forName(this.DRIVER);
            this.conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            // Definimos o objeto responsÃ¡vel por executar os comandos
            this.stm = this.getConexao().createStatement();
            return "sucesso";

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            this.conexao = null;
            return "Não foi possivel encontrar o driver de banco: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.conexao = null;
            return "SQLException Erro!" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public String fechaConexao() {
        try {
            if (this.getConexao() != null) {
                this.getConexao().close();
                this.conexao = null;
            }
            if (this.getStm() != null) {
                this.stm = null;
            }
            return "Conexão Encerrada";
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return "Houve erro no fechamento da conexão! "+ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConexao() {
        return conexao;
    }

    public Statement getStm() {
        return stm;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

}
```

Certifique-se de que o banco de dados existe, de que o nome de usuário e senha estejam certos, e que você adicionou o [.jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) do driver [`JDBC do MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) no seu projeto. O driver JDBC é o responsável por fazer a integração do Java com o banco de dados.

Se estiver usando o NetBeans, clique em `Bibliotecas` com o botão direito, depois vá em `Adicionar Biblioteca...`, como mostra a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procure por [`Driver JDBC do MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) e adicione ao seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se não funcionar, me avisa ;)

Comment: O que seria o .jar do driver?

Comment: @LuizSantos editei a minha resposta. Você está usando o NetBeans?

Comment: Estou sim. Vou adicionar e verificar se funciona. Voltarei com o feed, obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar as mensagens de erro a sua pergunta? (Se houverem)

Comment: @Avelino

Então, só é possível crude quando configuramos o driver de conexão, né isso? É que postei duas dúvidas com base num exemplo do blog do Camilo Lopes. As dúvidas:

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89842/o-que-fazer-depois-do-mapeamento/89854?noredirect=1#comment181874_89854
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90033/conex%C3%A3o-com-database-e-mapeamento/90035#90035