# O que fazer depois do mapeamento?

Tags: java, mysql

Quero fazer um sisteminha para colocar e buscar dados num banco. É uma agenda que o usuário insere o local, o compromisso e a prioridade. Por enquanto, é só. Já comecei nos mapeamentos. A pergunta é:

Preciso do MySQL Connector para Java?

Eu quero fazer para desktop, pois das vezes que tentei usar o comando

`java -j nome do arquivo.jar`, dá erro. Não sei se é em alguma instalação. Logo, quero fazer em desktop. Antes tentei fazer java web, usando JPA.

Já comecei com o mapeamento:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "agenda")
public class Agenda implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "local")
    private String local;

    @Column(name = "compromisso")
    private String compromisso;

    @Column(name = "prioridade")
    private String prioridade;

    /*
        public Agenda() {
            super();
        }

        public Agenda(String local, String compromisso, String prioridade) {
this.local=local;           
            this.compromisso=compromisso;
            this.prioridade=prioridade;
        }
     */

    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }

    public void setLocal(String local) {
        this.local=local;
    }

    public String getCompromisso() {
        return compromisso; 
    }

    public setCompromisso(String compromisso) {
        this.compromisso=compromisso;
    }

    public String getPrioridade() {
        return prioridade;
    }

    public void setPrioridade(String prioridade) {
        this.prioridade=prioridade;
    }

}
```

Comment: Você só quer saber se precisa do MySQL Connector?

Comment: @jbueno

Além disso, saber o que faço em seguida. Configurar o banco, criar xml, o que fazer?

Comment: Bom, primeiramente você não disse isso na sua pergunta. Também acho que sua pergunta se encaixaria como **ampla demais** se você perguntasse tudo isso junto. Talvez seria melhor você procurar algum material de como se conectar com o banco de dados em *Java*...

Answer (score 1):

Bem, vou ver se posso te ajudar. Primeiro configuramos criamos e configuramos o `hibernate.cfg.xml`(Caso ainda não tenha configurado).

hibernate.cfg:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- CONFIGURAÇÕES DO BANCO, TROCAR "NOMEDOBANCO" PARA O NOME DO SEU BANCO QUE JÁ FOI CRIADO -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/NOMEDOBANCO</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Dropa e Recria todas as tabelas, mudar para update ou validade após primeira execução -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        //AQUI VOCÊ MAPEIA SUA CLASSE AGENDA.
        <mapping class="com.sistema.model.Agenda" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Feito isso precisamos configurar o Hibernate, para isso utilizamos uma classe utilitária.

**HibernateUtil:** (Coloque essa Classe dentro do pacote util)

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Depois te ter feito esses passos e ter as **bibliotecas** do `Hibernate` e `Mysql` em seu projeto voce pode criar uma classe de teste:

```
public class GeraTabela {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        //TESTE
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Se tudo der certo quando você executar essa classe sua tabela será criada no banco de dados.

Caso queria salvar os dados no banco vamos fazer uma classe que realizará todas as regras que envolvem o banco.

**AgendaDAO:** (Criar essa classe no pacote DAO, ex com.sistema.dao)

```
//Método recebe uma agenda(objeto) como parâmetro.
public void salvar(Agenda agenda) {
        //Abre uma sessão e armazena na variável sessão
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            //Iniciamos uma nova transação
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            //Salvamos a Agenda
            sessao.save(agenda);
            //Comitamos a transação
            transacao.commit();

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }

    }
```

Agora podemos testar:
Crie a classe **AgendaDAOTeste** e faça o seguinte:

```
public class AgendaDAOTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Isntancia(Cria) uma nova agenda
        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
        //Instancia o DAO
        AgendaDAO agendaDao = new AgendaDAO();

        //Setamos alguns atributos para a nossa agenda
        agenda.setLocal("São Paulo");
        agenda.setCompromisso("Reunião");
        agenda.setPrioridade("Urgente");

        //Salvamos a agenda criada
        agendaDao.salvar(agenda);

    }

}
```

Comment: Vou segui estas orientações, qualquer coisa comento, além do positivo.

Comment: Tudo bem, eu comentei as principais partes, faça um esforço e  tente entender como tudo funciona que você irá aprender.

Comment: O hibernate.cfg.xml posso criar na mão mesmo, né?

Só lembrando que estou pensando em desk top e não web, já que é coisa bem simples. Mas se for inveredar para web, vai ser mais difícil, Techies mas fazer o que, né?

Comment: Essa parte é quase mesma coisa. Não vai mudar muito de Desk pra Web, o que mais vai mudar é a maneira em que você irá receber os dados.

Comment: O hibernate.cfg crio na raiz do projeto?

Falei da configuração, porque segui este tutorial:
https://camilolopes.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/criando-conexao-java-mysql-com-eclipse/

Comment: pode ser, eu costumo coloca-lo na pasta resources.