# Conexão com database e mapeamento

Tags: java

@Techies

Refiz a pergunta com um título apropriado, com base na dúvida inicial em:

[O que fazer depois do mapeamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89842/o-que-fazer-depois-do-mapeamento/89854?noredirect=1#comment181874_89854)

Olá.

Seguindo as orientações de outro post, tenho algumas dúvidas, começando com o arquivo hibernate.cfg:

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- CONFIGURAÇÕES DO BANCO, TROCAR "NOMEDOBANCO" PARA O NOME DO SEU BANCO QUE JÁ FOI CRIADO -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">portal</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Dropa e Recria todas as tabelas, mudar para update ou validade após primeira execução -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <!--AQUI VOCÊ MAPEIA SUA CLASSE AGENDA.-->
    <mapping class="com.sistema.model.Agenda" />
</session-factory>
```

Neste arquivo o usuário que me ajudou fala em mapear a classe agenda. A dúvida é:

1. Mesmo assim, preciso mapear minha tabela em outra classe usando Entity?
2. E sobre comandos ddl que ele fala nas linhas de comentários, significa que será um processo dinâmico? Sempre vai dropar e recriar? Desculpe, estou tentanto entender. Por isso tanta pergunta.

O HibernateUtil: (Coloque essa Classe dentro do pacote util). A dúvida é:

1. Eu crio o package util? Onde encontro o util? Também não entendi, mas uma vez desculpas.

   ```
   public class HibernateUtil {

   private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

   private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
       try {
           // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
           Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
           configuration.configure();

           ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                   .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

           SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
           return sessionFactory;

       } catch (Throwable ex) {
           // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
           System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
           throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
       }
   }

   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
       return sessionFactory;
   }
   ```

   }

E o usuário fala em classe de teste para gerar tabela:

```
public class GeraTabela {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        //TESTE
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Se tudo der certo quando você executar essa classe sua tabela será criada no banco de dados.

Volto para a pergunta acima: sempre será DDL?

Um abraço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

1: Mesmo assim, preciso mapear minha tabela em outra classe usando Entity?

**R:** Não, pois você já a mapeou no arquivo `hibernate.cfg`

---

2: E sobre comandos ddl que ele fala nas linhas de comentários, significa que será um processo dinâmico? Sempre vai dropar e recriar?

**R:** Também não, você utiliza o `create` para criar as tabelas no banco, o `create` dropa todas as tabelas e as recria novamente. Após ter usado o `create` pela primeira vez você pode trocar para `update` ou `validate`. De uma pesquisada sobre o que cada um faz que você entenderá melhor

---

3: Eu crio o package util? Onde encontro o util?

**R:** Você pode colocar essa classe em qualquer pacote, mas é recomendado deixa-la no pacote `util`, você poderá utilizar essa classe em todos os seus projetos, recomendo que de uma pesquisada sobre classes utilitárias também.

---

E pra ultima pergunta, a única coisa que você tem que trocar são os valores passados para a propriedade `hbm2ddl.auto`: **CREATE**, **UPDATE** E **VALIDATE**. Se for a primeira vez que você irá rodar o sistema as tabelas ainda não vão estar geradas, então utilize um `create` veja se as tabelas foram criadas e em seguida troque para `update` ou `validate`.

Comment: A tabela já está criada, vou pesquisar sobre o update e validate, já que o create não interessa, pelo menos agora.

Comment: que tipo de projeto devo criar para java web? Seria jpa? Estou perguntando porque os projetos têm sua estrutura e se eu estiver alguma dúvida, ajuda a passar detalhes.

Comment: Depende, se for com Maven, crie um maven project. Se quiser um web normal crie um dynamic web project

Comment: no hibernate.cfg, na linha

<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> mudei para
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

O tipo do projeto criei no java for EE do tipo dynamic web project.

Comment: Beleza, se você quiser dar uma estudada e aprender um pouco de tudo, aqui tem um curso gratuito: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PGp1T242hA&list=PL_GwGUsBlNyfI0W3ggfffhBdJUqB4981Z