# Como funciona o Padrão DAO?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Pesquisei e li a respeito do *Padrão DAO (Data Access Object)*, porém não estou conseguindo entender como é o seu funcionamento e como é a estrutura dele, ele também é responsável pelas regras de negócio de uma aplicação? Ou ele é apenas responsável pelo **CRUD** e pelas **transações** e **conexões**?

*Obs: De preferência, se puder mostrar sua implementação e seu funcionamento prático em Java.*

Comment: Por que a tag Java?

Comment: Veja a edição, esqueci de mencionar que eu gostaria de ver como ele e usado em Java.

Comment: O DAO é o intermediário com o banco de dados, ele faz conexão e transações com este. Quem trata a regra de negócio é o model. Mas são conceitos que causam um pouco de confusão mesmo para quem não tem costume com design patterns mesmo.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe ele é parte de algum outro padrão? Ou o DAO é uma coisa só? Espero que alguém responda também, o pessoal esta usando ele na faculdade mais ninguém entende o que é e como funciona para poder usa-lo.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Definição

Em resumo, DAO é um padrão de projetos onde um objeto:

- provê uma interface que abstrai o acesso a dados;
- lê e grava a partir da origem de dados (banco de dados, arquivo, memória, etc.); e

  - encapsula o acesso aos dados, de forma que as demais classes não precisam saber sobre isso.

## Arquitetura

Numa aplicação web comum seguindo o modelo MVC, os DAOs ficam junto com o Model fazendo um trabalho de suporte, integrando a fonte de dados ao modelo de objetos do sistema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [Introdução ao JDBC](http://www.slideshare.net/utluiz/introduo-ao-jdbc)

## Responsabilidades

Seguindo o princípio de responsabilidade única, um DAO não deve ser responsável por mais do que acesso aos dados.

Definir quem faz o que pode ser um problema quando pensamos na arquitetura de um sistema, mas grande parte disso é porque misturamos as coisas.

Se olhar bem o diagrama acima, fica fácil identificarmos a responsabilidade de cada elemento.

Suponha que o usuário está acessando a página inicial do sistema web. Então uma interação comum poderia ser:

1. Um *controller* recebe a requisição do usuário
2. Esse *controller* chama o método do *service* adequado para obter as informações para aquela página
3. O *service* chama um ou mais métodos de *DAOs* para obter as informações necessárias e retorna os dados para o *controller*
4. O *controller* recebe os dados e redireciona o usuário para uma *view* que vai renderizar o HTML da página

Adicionalmente, temos que:

- Controllers executam lógica relacionada à navegação do usuário no sistema, isto é, qual URL ou qual ação exibe qual página.
- Services executam a lógica do sistema, que pode incluir gerenciar transações e processar os dados

Portanto, em geral, cada método do DAO deve fazer uma única leitura ou gravação no banco de dados e não deve controlar transações ou realizar operações adicionais, tal como realizar alterações nos dados recebidos do serviço.

Posso dizer por experiência que muitas vezes é uma tentação você colocar regras de negócio ou controle transacional no DAO, afinal é um lugar pelo qual toda informação vai eventualmente passar. Porém, cedo ou tarde isso vai entrar em conflito com alguma outra parte do sistema. Portanto, se houver uma regra comum a ser aplicada em uma entidade, crie um serviço específico para isso e faça com que todos os outros serviços apontem para ele.

## Implementação

A vantagem de usar uma classe específica para o acesso a dados é evitar espalhar SQLs em todo lugar, tornando a manutenção e evolução de um sistema um pesadelo.

Em geral, agrupa-se os acessos aos dados por similaridade, por exemplo, uma classe por tabela. Porém, não é sempre que isso faz sentido, principalmente quando o sistema não é somente feito de cadastros simples (CRUD).

Um exemplo claro são sistemas que possuem buscas avançadas em que acessam várias tabelas. Nesse caso, cada situação precisa ser analisada caso a caso. No exemplo das buscas, um DAO específico para isso seria interessante.

Usar interfaces é opcional. Veja, Java tem uma péssima reputação por usar muitas interfaces, mas isso tem seus motivos, por exemplo:

- Permitir várias implementações para bancos de dados diferentes sem alterar o sistema
- Permitir versões diferentes convivendo na mesma versão do sistema (isso pode ser útil em alguns casos, como quando algum campo pode ou não existir e você quer atualizar o sistema sem obrigar a criação do campo)
- Facilitar testes unitários criando implementações Fakes dos DAOs, por exemplo, que usam listas em memória, embora frameworks como Mockito consigam gerar mocks dinamicamente sem uma interface

### Com Interface

Tenho [um exemplo bem simples, mas completo, no meu GitHub](https://github.com/utluiz/spring-examples/tree/master/agenda-web-completa/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/agenda/dao) de um DAO que encapsula a entidade `Usuario`.

A interface fica assim:

```
public interface UsuarioDao {
    Usuario findByNomeUsuario(String string);
    void atualizarUltimoAcesso(Integer id, Date data);
}
```

E a implementação usando Spring JDBC Template:

```
public class UsuarioDaoImpl implements UsuarioDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Usuario findByNomeUsuario(String nomeUsuario) {
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                    "select * from usuario where nome_usuario = ?", 
                    new UsuarioRowMapper(), 
                    nomeUsuario);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void atualizarUltimoAcesso(Integer id, Date data) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "update usuario set ultimo_acesso = ? where id = ?", data, id);
    }

}
```

### Sem Interface

O mesmo DAO sem interface e usando JDBC puro [fica assim](https://github.com/utluiz/spring-examples/blob/master/agenda-dao-jdbc/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/agenda/dao/UsuarioDao.java):

```
public class UsuarioDao {

    private DataSource ds;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }

    public Usuario findByNomeUsuario(String string) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from usuario where nome_usuario = ?");
            ps.setString(1, string);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                Usuario usuario =  new Usuario();
                usuario.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                usuario.setNomeUsuario(rs.getString("nome_usuario"));
                usuario.setSenha(rs.getString("senha"));
                usuario.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                usuario.setUltimoAcesso(rs.getTimestamp("ultimo_acesso"));
                return usuario;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void atualizarUltimoAcesso(Integer id, Date data) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("update usuario set ultimo_acesso = ? where id = ?");
            ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(data.getTime()));
            ps.setInt(2, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Devemos usar DAO hoje em dia?

Muitos diriam que não.

ORMs como Hibernate ou Eclipselink tentam fazer todo o trabalho pesado para transitar os dados entre os objetos e as tabelas. Já vi sistemas que manipulavam diretamente as entidades JPA nas regras de negócio.

Eu diria que esse tipo de solução não é escalável, o que significa que vai gerar problemas na medida em que o sistema cresce. Justamente por causa disso, muitos usam o padrão de projeto Repository, que é um tipo de DAO um pouco diferente, mesmo quando usam JPA.

Na minha opinião, o padrão DAO ainda é, em geral, a melhor forma de se implementar a interface com o banco de dados em um sistema. Digo isso porque interagir com o banco é uma responsabilidade que faz parte de quase todo sistema e, se você não colocar no DAO, vai acabar colocando em algum outro lugar. E você não vai querer misturar responsabilidades, vai?

Comment: Queria poder votar várias vezes nessa resposta. Muito bom!

Answer (score 13):

O padrão DAO tem como principal propósito abstrair o acesso a fonte de dados da sua aplicação (geralmente um banco de dados como postgresql, mysql, mongodb, etc) das partes que utilizam ou provém estes dados. O problema que ele tenta resolver é o de que a fonte dos seus dados pode mudar, pode ser por exemplo que você atualmente possua uma aplicação em produção feita em cima de mongodb contudo acabou de descobrir que este possui certos problemas de consistência de dados que você não pode tolerar e resolveu migrar para um banco que de garantias maiores de integridade, e neste cenário caso suas funções de acesso ao banco estejam misturada com partes da lógica de seu código (como as regra de negócio por exemplo) você seria obrigado a refatora-lás, o que é um problema pois dado que seu código esteja estável você não quer ficar fazendo alterações que possam fazer com ele venha a quebrar. Caso você tenha uma camada DAO separada da sua camada lógica a alteração da fonte de dados se torna simplesmente uma questão de criar uma nova interface de acesso para a nova fonte, mantendo suas regras de negócio intocadas.

O DAO "clássico" é divido em três partes, uma interface que define os métodos que o objeto de acesso irá prover, a classe que representa seu modelo de dados e a classe que realiza o acesso aos dados, exemplo para o caso da sua aplicação hipotética que tem uma entidade `Curso` e atualmente utiliza mongodb:

Modelo de dados:

```
public class Curso {
    public long id;
    public String nome;

    public Curso(long id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;

        // finja que aqui existem
        // regras hiper complicadas de processamento
        // da variável "nome"

        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Interface que define os métodos de acesso ao banco:

```
interface CursoDAO {
    public Curso create(String name);

    public void update(long id, Curso curso);

    public void delete(long id);

    public Curso findByName(String name);
}
```

Finalmente sua implementação do DAO que acessa o banco (mongodb):

```
public class CursoDAOMongodb implements CursoDAO {

    public Curso create(long id, String name) {
        // realiza a conexão necessária com a mongodb
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("minha incrivel database");   

        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("curso");
        document.put("id", id);
        document.put("name", name);
        table.insert(document);

        return new Curso(id, name);
    }

    public Curso findByName(String name) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("minha incrivel database");   
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("name", name);

        // etc, pega os dados da query e retorna um new Curso com eles
    }

    public void delete(long id) {
        // realiza a conexão necessária com a mongodb e executa o DELETE no banco
    }

    public void update(long id, Curso curso) {
        // realiza a conexão necessária com a mongodb e executa o UPDATE no banco
    }
}
```

No seu código que consome e provê os dados ao banco você teria algo assim:

```
// digamos que suas regras de negócio estejam na Main
public class Main() {

    static public CursoDAO getDbAcessorForCurso() {
        return new CursoDAOMongodb();
    }

    public static void main(String javaehverborragico[]) {

        String[] nomes = {"design", "pattern", "dao"};

        List<Curso> cursos = new ArrayList<Curso>();

        CursoDAO dbAcessor = Main.getDbAcessorForCurso();

        // criando cursos
        for (String nome : nomes) {
            Curso novoCurso = dbAcessor.create(nome);
            cursos.add(novoCurso);
        }

        // ...
        // realize outras operações de delete ou select usando
        // dbAcessor
    }
}
```

Note o método `getDbAcessorForCurso`, ele é responsável por te retornar o objeto do seu DAO de acesso atual que no caso é o que usa mongodb. Agora, continuando na ideia do início da resposta, você está desiludido com NoSQL e quer voltar a um bom e velho SGBD relacional, vamos dizer postgresql, o que você faz? apenas cria uma nova implementação para `CursoDAO`, dessa vez uma que utilize postgresql:

```
public class CursoDAOPostgresql implements CursoDAO {

    public Curso create(long id, String name) {
        // realiza a conexão necessária com a mongodb
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/minha incrivel database");

        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO curso (id, name) VALUES (" + id + ", " + name + ") ";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();

        return new Curso(id, name);
    }

    // ... outros métodos de CursoDAO, mesma ideia.
}
```

Agora tudo está pronto para você passar a usar postgresql no lugar de mongodb sem que o resto da sua aplicação note a diferença, basta alterar o método que te retorna seu objeto DAO para que ele passe a retornar sua nova imlementação:

```
public class Main() {

    static public CursoDAO getDbAcessor() {
        return new CursoDAOPostgresql();
    }
    ...
```

Pronto, você migrou de um banco de dados para outro alterando exclusivamente a parte que interage com a fonte de dados, a implementação DAO, nada de altearções no meio do seu modelo de dados `Curso` ou nas suas regras de negócio que neste caso estão em `Main`.

Duas notas finais:

1. Este é um exemplo extremamente simplificado (e olha o tamanho da coisa), talvez as vantagens não fiquem tão evidentes nesta escala então tente imaginar situações mais complexas com inúmeras regras de negócio permeando o código.
2. DAO é um padrão Java no coração, o que significa que ele costuma gerar toneladas de classes e interfaces. Embora seja um ótimo pattern e resolva problemas reais cuidado para não abusar, você não precisa seguir ele a risca, implementações simplificadas geralmente são preferíveis caso você não esteja desenhando mega [ERPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) em que a alteração de uma parte menos flexível do sistema pode durar duas gerações da sua família. Também caso você esteja simplesmente prototipando algum sistema ou fazendo algo realmente simples não faz sentido complicar seu código com um pattern cujas vantagens nunca vão ser realmente usadas. Sempre análise a situação antes de sair usando padrões, pode ser que a adição de complexidade que eles tragam não compense a flexibilidade ganha.

Comment: Mas seu eu for usar uma classe DAO por classe model, não tem porque eu fazer uma interface né? Afinal, eu só vou ter uma implementação do DAO daquele model específico. A menos que eu fizesse uma interface que nas buscas por exemplo, retornasse um Object, aí sim eu poderia usar essa interface para todos os DAO do meu sistema. Mas suspeito que isso também não é uma boa ideia, certo?  @BrunoRB

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

O Padrão DAO ou DAL nada mais é do que parte do conceito arquitetural `Three-Tier`(três Camadas em português) esse modelo programacional tem por finalidade distinguir as camadas de apresentação, processamento, e acesso a dados fisicamente.

Em suma você basicamente dividiria o modelo monolítico de aplicações em um modelo onde cada camada possui uma responsabilidade dentro do sistema.

A distribuição de uma aplicação em 3 camadas por ser concebida em diferentes assemblies(packages) e até mesmo em diferentes máquinas físicas se comunicando através de serviços e webservices dentre outros meios.

---

[image: Three-Tier]

### Camada de Apresentação (Presentation Tier):

Esta camada constitui o mais alto nível da arquitetura a mesma tem por finalidade comportar os componentes quais serão apresentados em tela(`UI`) e seus respectivos precessores, em geral você utilizará a mesma como ponte entre as informações que serão exibidas e o conteúdo presente nas demais camadas.

Qualquer interação com usuário sendo entrada ou saída de dados deve ficar alocada neste nível da arquitetura.

Outras Denominações: `UI(User Interface)` ou `VIEW`

### Camada Lógica (Logic Tier):

Camada responsável por gerir o processamento lógico da aplicação, esta camada basicamente tem por finalidade agregar todo o processamento complexo da aplicação afim de garantir a unicidade de responsabilidade sobre as regras de negócio do sistema ou seja tudo que for complexo, exigir a junção de várias entidades, algoritmos complexos e regras de dados.

Alguns arquitetos optam por centralizar o acesso as camadas de dados nas camadas de negócio. 
Apesar de redundante, existindo a necessidade aplicar regras de negócios nas consultas simples esta redundância remove a necessidade de intervenção nas demais camadas posteriormente.

Outras Denominações: `BO(Business Object)` ou `BLL(Business Logic Layer)`

### Camada de Dados (Data Tier):

Camada responsável por agregar os mecanismos de persistência, entidades e métodos responsáveis por prover o acesso ao banco de dados, nesta famigerada camada geralmente é provido para cada entidade uma classe contendo os métodos de adição, deleção, listagem e remoção além das consultas especificas que cada entidade pode exigir.

Outras Denominações: `DAL(Data Access Layer)`, `DAO(Data Access Object)` ou `Repository`

### Resumo:

Durante o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação, a arquitetura de três camadas fornece muitos benefícios, tais como a capacidade de reutilização, flexibilidade, gerenciamento, manutenção e escalabilidade.

Ganhos com este tipo de implementação:

- Possibilidade de reutilização dos componentes e distribuição entre distintas aplicações.
- Possibilidade de dividir projetos grandes e complexos em projetos mais simples e atribui-los a diferentes times ou recursos garantindo a unicidade dos componentes de acesso a dados e regras de negócio.

Perdas ou problemas com este tipo de implementação:

- Perda de produtividade se comparado com o desenvolvimento monolítico.
- Aumento do trafego de dados se implementada em distintas máquinas.
- Aumento da complexidade na implementação dos projetos.

---

Referências:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685068(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648105.aspx
- http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/j2ee/html/intro/intro.htm

Comment: Eu dei +1 na resposta pelo esforço, mas ela não responde exatamente o que é DAO. A resposta fala muito sobre camadas e quase nada sobre o *design pattern*.