# CascadeType.ALL não funciona. Estou usando errado?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

No meu código, tenho as classes **Autor** e **Livro**, com o relacionamento **Many To One**, como abaixo:

## Autor.java

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
@Entity
public class Autor implements Serializable{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Livro> livros;

    // outras coisas...
}
```

## Livro.java

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
@Entity
public class Livro implements Serializable{
    @ManyToOne
    private Autor autor;

    // outras coisas...
}
```

Obs.: Estou usando MYSQL e Hibernate 3.
Eu consigo fazer as operações básicas com esse código: criar, ler, atualizar e remover. Porém eu só consigo apagar um `Autor` que não tenha nenhum `Livro` relacionado a ele. Quando tento apagar um `Autor` que tenha `Livros`, recebo esse erro:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`livros`.`livro`, CONSTRAINT `FK4607E763FA6B4EF` FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `autor` (`id`))

Gostaria que quando apagasse um Autor que já tem Livros relacionados, esses também fossem removidos do banco de dados. Achei que o objetivo do `CascadeType.ALL` fosse esse, porém não obtive sucesso usando-o. Onde estou errando?
Obrigado.

## EDIT 1

Procurando mais um pouco na internet sobre esse problema, me deparei com [esse site](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/).
Lá é dito que não se pode misturar anotações JPA com Hibernate (justamente o que eu estava fazendo).
Substituí `@OneToMany([...], cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` por `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)`, porém sem sucesso. Abaixo a classe modificada e o método delete da minha classe `Dao`.

## Autor.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
@Entity
public class Autor implements Serializable{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Livro> livros;

    // outras coisas...
}
```

## Dao.java

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
public class Dao <Classe>{
    public void delete(Classe c){
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(c);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
    // Outras coisas...
}
```

## EDIT 2

Em resposta, o Marcos disse que não se deve misturar JPA com Hibernate, porém era assim que eu estava fazendo desde o início (e não funcionava). Procurei exemplos na internet, e minha classe está basicamente igual a todas as outras; a única diferença é que não consigo fazer isso funcionar. É possível que isso seja problema de versão do Hibernate? Uso o 3.5.6.

## EDIT 3

Como o Marcos Sousa pediu, aqui está o meu projeto completo no Github: https://github.com/mateusbandeiraa/Livros

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na realidade,**(nota de edição 1: Não é aconselhado a "mistura")** não deves misturar anotações **Hibernate** em **JPA**. a **JPA** é a especificação e o **Hibernate** a implementa, em casos de mudanças de implementação, para o **EclipseLink** por exemplo, não haveria problemas já que ambas implementam a **JPA**, ou seja, **JPA** é o padrão.

**1º** Tenha em mente a utilização e padronização da **JPA** em seu código.

**2º** Sobre o relacionamento de suas entidades:
em casos em que um **Livro** é escrito por vários autores? Não seria um relacionamento **ManyToMany**?

**3º** Tente atualizar a biblioteca do **Hibernate**, não terá muitos problemas **(nota de edição 2: estou usando o hibernate na versão 5.2.3.Final)**.

**4º** segue um código auxiliar, **(nota de edição 3)** com relacionamento *OneToMany* bidirecional.

**LIVRO**

```
package br.com.livraria.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
public class Livro implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String titulo; 

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="autor_id")
    private Autor autor;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public Autor getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }
    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }


}
```

**AUTOR**

```
package br.com.livraria.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Autor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="autor", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Livro> getLivros() {
        return livros;
    }

    public void setLivros(List<Livro> livros) {
        this.livros = livros;
    }

}
```

**5º** Refatorei a concepção do seu código, porém em meu ambiente de configuração: estou utilizando um servidor de aplicação WildFly(com a biblioteca do hibernate nativa) e todas as anotações seguem o padrão JPA. Os testes me levaram ao mesmo erro apresentado pelo seu código, depois configurei o `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` em ambos os lados do relacionamento e funcionou.Portando para o erro apresentado, essas duas entidades que postei devem bastar, porém se surgir outros erros discutiremos mais.

**Resposta ao EDIT 3**

**6º** Bom, esse problema é em relação ao seu método.
não entendo muito de **Spring** (acho que é), mas a lógica é a seguinte:

```
@Transactional
    public void removeAutor(Integer autorId){

        Autor autor = autorDAO.buscarPorId(autorId);

        List<Livro> livros = autor.getLivros();

        for (Livro livro : livros) {
            System.out.println(livro.getTitulo() + " LISTA DE LIVROS ADICIONADOS");
            livro.setAutor(null);

        }

        autorDAO.remove(autor);
    }
```

**Explicação do meu método**

- Recebo uma **Id** (`Integer`) da minha View;
- Declaro a entidade e a inicio com a pesquisa do método: **buscarPorId(autorId);**;
- Declaro uma lista de `Livro` e a inicio com os livros do autor: **autor.getLivros();**
- Percorro essa lista de livros e a atualizo essa instancia, desvinculando `Autor` de `Livro` (ponto chave);
- faço a **remoção** (delete) do autor pesquisado: **autorDAO.remove(autor);**

**Lógica**

- Deves pesquisar a entidade **Autor** pela **Id**.
- A parti dessa entidade, vc busca a lista de **Livro**.
- Essa lista de livros vc atualiza para `null`, com o `setter`, pronto! vc desvinculou o `Autor` desses `livros`.
- daí é só fazer a exclusão normal do `Autor`, que não irã apagar os livros.

**NOTA:**

1. **@Transactional** - faz todo o jogo de transação automaticamente, então não preciso iniciar nem fecha uma transações (**beginTransaction()**).
2. Sua estrutura de DAO tá muito limitada, deves encapsular a lógica do DAO genérico e usar polimorfismo conforme a necessidade do seu **Modelo**. Dê uma olhada nesse tópico [Como funciona o Padrão DAO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113840/como-funciona-o-padr%C3%A3o-dao), Vai precisa para organizar melhor seu código.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!
1. Eu acho que você inverteu os títulos **AUTOR** & **LIVRO** na sua resposta: Livro tem uma lista `livros` e Autor tem uma lista `autores`?
2. Obrigado pelo toque no relacionamento, mas é um projeto simples e eu estou testando todas os relacionamentos. Many To Many foi implementado em outras classes desse mesmo projeto.
3. Fiz o teste do jeito que você mandou: Livro tem uma lista de Autores & Autor tem uma lista de Livros. Usei o `Cascade = CascadeType.ALL` do JPA, porém ainda recebo o erro. Será que isso pode ser problema de versão? Estou usando HIBERNATE 3.5.6

Comment: @MateusBandeira obrigado pelo feed, estou na mesma linha de pesquisa então estamos no mesmo barco. Realmente errei na declaração das variáveis, o código já está ajustado. vc também poderia, caso haja necessidade, mandar seu ambiente de configuração.

Comment: Não tenho muita ideia do que pode interferir para causar esse erro, mas estou usando o Tomcat 8 e Hibernate 3.5.6-final como dependência do Maven (`hibernate-entitymanager`). Coloquei o `Cascade` nas duas classes, mas o erro persiste. No mesmo projeto, copiei e colei as suas classes integralmente. O erro persiste. Acredito que falta alguma dependência ou a versão que uso está com algum problema. Continuo pesquisando...

Comment: @MateusBandeira continua apresentando o mesmo erro?
como estão seus métodos de exclusão?
poste seu persistence.xml e o arquivo POM.xml.
como vc está controlando as transações da sua aplicação?

Comment: @MateusBandeira, vc pode compartilhar seu projeto completo, para eu dar uma analisada?

Comment: Fiz o teste com o Hibernate 4.1.1 e o problema continua. Então dificilmente seria um problema de versão... A respeito de compartilhar o código, não há problema algum; ele está no Github: https://github.com/mateusbandeiraa/Livros

Comment: @MateusBandeira, toda questão é o método de exclusão!
vc terá que "romper" a relação que as entidades possuem e a partir dai excluir o autor.

Comment: @MateusBandeira, vc deverá pegar a lógica da resposta e adaptar ao seu código.

Comment: você tá falando em resgatar todos os livros do autor, e apagá-los antes, né? Já havia pensado nisso. Mas não seria uma gambiarra? Vou acabar fazendo isso mesmo.