# Arquivos DAO em PHP é necessário?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, design-pattern

Gostaria de saber se classes do tipo DAO é necessário no PHP?

Ex: ProdutoDAO

Vejo muitas pessoas programando sem colocar arquivos DAO mesmo em uma plataforma MVC.

Estou aprendendo programação Orientada a Objetos em minha faculdade, e o professor encaminha o usuário a criar arquivos DAO para separação de responsábilidades.

Ouvindo um podcast do @Hipster, percebi que os desenvolvedores da @stackoverflow colocam querys direto no controller. Isso também é legal?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como funciona o Padrão DAO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113840/91).

Comment: @rray Eu li essa postagem. Apesar de ser quase a mesma coisa, eu funilei a questão focando no PHP.

Comment: Quando levamos os conceitos de boas práticas para a comunidade, o que podemos encontrar de surpresa?
Sabemos que ainda uma grande parte da comunidade PHP ainda possuí uma péssima prática. E não sei se isso é correto, pois me deparei com vários sistemas de uma grande empresa, e encontro várias coisas que fogem do meu princípio!

Comment: O conceito de DAO é independende da linguagem, a resposta em Java será a mesma para o PHP. "Princípios" na teoria são o estado-da-arte. Entretanto, não é a mesma coisa na prática. Você encontrará coisa errada em pequenas, médias e grandes empresas.

Comment: Se não colocar a lógica de acesso a banco de dados em um dao é provavel que coloque em um model :). A ideia é centralizar essas operações em um classe se você coloca direto no controller fica difícil a reutilização além de espalhar esse código por toda a aplicação. No cast também diz que essa solução é adotada pela performace já que abstrações tem um custo (pode ser um pouco a mais ou muito).

Answer (score 2):

Um DAO não é ligado ao MVC nem pertencente ao *PHP*, mas você comumente vera os dois sendo empregados juntos DAO e MVC e tambem e comum ver DAO no *PHP* por se tratar de uma boa pratica. O DAO fica correto se relacionado a um Model do padrao.

O DAO, *data acess object*, como ja diz o nome, trata das conexoes de um modelo com sua persistencia, um SGBD como *PostgreSQL* ou até meio arquivos de texto por exemplo, entao é comum ser confundida com o Controller, mas esta errado.

Segue um links de exemplo:

http://www.guj.com.br/t/padrao-dao-e-mvc/274701/7

Comment: Legal!
Falando em questão de desempenho... Seria significativo fazer esse passeio entre as responsábilidades?
Acontece aqui na Stackoverflow! Eles criam a query dentro do controller, e não dentro de um model. Isso teria perda de um desempenho?

Comment: Bom, eu creio que isso não influência tanto, mas fere o próprio padrão MVC, nao é uma boa prática.