# Erro ao armazenar dados de um Select com Java

Tags: java, jdbc

Bom dia galerinha. Gostaria de saber se tem a possibilidade de armazenar em uma variável o valor de uma pesquisa (`select`). No caso eu quero armazenar um `id` de outra tabela com a utilização de um `select`, contudo após fazer o `.executeQuery()`, ele não me envia esse `id`.

```
String nomeCliente = (String) cbNomeCliente.getSelectedItem(); // receber o que está escrito no combobox
String nomeFuncionario = (String) cbNomeFuncionario.getSelectedItem();
String nomeLivro = (String) cbNomeLivro.getSelectedItem();

String sql, sqlChamaChaveCliente, sqlChamaChaveFuncionario, sqlChamaChaveLivro;
ResultSet recebeCli, recebeFunc, recebeLivro; 

try{
   //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
   stm = conexao.createStatement();

   sqlChamaChaveCliente = (String) "select idcliente from cliente where nome='" + nomeCliente +"'";
   sqlChamaChaveFuncionario = (String) "select idfuncionario from funcionario where nome ='" + nomeFuncionario+"'";
   sqlChamaChaveLivro = (String) "select idLivro from livro where nome_liv ='" + nomeLivro +"'";

   recebeCli   =   stm.executeQuery(sqlChamaChaveCliente);
   recebeFunc  =   stm.executeQuery(sqlChamaChaveFuncionario);
   recebeLivro =   stm.executeQuery(sqlChamaChaveLivro);
```

São nestas variáveis "`recebeCli`", "`recebeFunc`" e "`recebeLivro`" que eu quero guardar o valor da consulta.

Observação: sou iniciante em java.

Comment: O que você quer fazer com esses ids depois? Porque você quer lê-los? Pergunto isso porque ter só os ids isolados não é algo que tenha muita serventia na prática e ficar exibindo os ids por aí, principalmente se forem gerados automaticamente, não é boa prática de programação. Então presumo que você queira fazer algo com esses ids, e dependendo do que for, você vai querer pesquisar mais do que apenas os ids.

Comment: Ah, e leia sobre [**injeção de SQL**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). Para evitar esse problema, use `PreparedStatement`s.

Comment: esse id's eu quero armazenas eles dentro de uma variável e posteriormente salva-los em outra tabela.

Comment: Estou tentando elaborar uma resposta boa, mas falta algumas informações para eu fazer isso. Sem elas, o máximo que consigo é uma resposta chinfrim. Poderia me dizer quais são os campos dessas tabelas?

Answer (score 6):

Em primeiro lugar, não existe razão para economizar letras no nome de variáveis, o que é uma má prática de programação.

Em segundo lugar, use o [**try-with-resources**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Em terceiro lugar, evite [**injeção de SQL**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) ao usar o [**`PreparedStatement`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Em quarto lugar, prefira utilizar o [**padrão DAO**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113840/132) para realizar esse tipo de coisa.

Supondo que oss campos da sua tabela `cliente` sejam `id`, `nome`, `telefone` e `cpf`, seu código fica mais ou menos assim:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ClienteDAO {
    private static String POR_NOME =
            "SELECT id, nome, telefone, cpf FROM cliente WHERE nome = ?";

    private static String POR_ID =
            "SELECT id, nome, telefone, cpf FROM cliente WHERE id = ?";

    private final Connection conexao;

    public ClienteDAO(Connection conexao) {
        this.conexao = conexao;
    }

    private Cliente popular(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        int id = rs.getInt(1);
        String nome = rs.getString(2);
        String telefone = rs.getString(3);
        String cpf = rs.getString(4);
        return Cliente.criar(id, nome, telefone, cpf);
    }

    private List<Cliente> listar(PreparedStatement statment) throws SQLException {
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            List<Cliente> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Cliente c = popular(rs);
                resultado.add(c);
            }
            return resultado;
        }
    }

    private Optional<Cliente> ler(PreparedStatement statment) throws SQLException {
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) return Optional.of(popular(rs));
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public List<Cliente> porNome(String nome) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = conexao.prepareStatement(POR_NOME)) {
            statement.setString(1, nome);
            return listar(statement);
        }
    }

    public Optional<Cliente> porId(int id) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = conexao.prepareStatement(POR_ID)) {
            statement.setInt(1, id);
            return ler(statement);
        }
    }
}
```

Outros métodos que tragam resultados da tabela `cliente` são adicionados a esta mesma classe. Você vai fazer algo parecido para as demais classes. Os métodos públicos corresponderão a cada tipo de consulta que o seu DAO é capaz de faazer e utilizarão os métodos privados `ler(PrepaparedStatement)` e `listar(PreparedStatement)` para formar os resultados.

Observe que os resultados podem ser uma `List<Cliente>` para o caso onde podem haver vários (ou nenhum) resultado. Para o caso onde só pode haver um ou nenhum resultado, você usa `Optional<Cliente>`.

Também é necessário haver um método `criar` na classe `Cliente` que cria uma instância contendo todos os dados necessários. Eu falo mais sobre isso [**nessa outra resposta minha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132).

Em seguida, você juntará os DAOs mais ou menos assim:

```java
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ParametrosDeConexao {

    private final String url;
    private final String usuario;
    private final String senha;

    public ParametrosDeConexao(String url, String usuario, String senha) {
        this.url = url;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CamadaDeDados implements AutoCloseable {
    private final Connection conexao;
    private final ClienteDAO clientes;
    private final FuncionarioDAO funcionarios;
    private final LivroDAO livros;

    public CamadaDeDados(ParametrosDeConexao params) throws SQLException {
        this.conexao = params.conectar();
        this.clientes = new ClienteDAO(conexao);
        this.funcionarios = new FuncionarioDAO(conexao);
        this.livros = new LivroDAO(conexao);
    }

    public ClienteDAO clientes() {
        return clientes;
    }

    public FuncionarioDAO funcionarios() {
        return funcionarios;
    }

    public LivroDAO livros() {
        return livros;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        conexao.close();
    }
}
```

Agora que temos a camada de acesso aos dados organizadas, você pode fazer isso:

```java
private ParametrosDeConexao params() {
    return new ParametrosDeConexao(url, usuario, senha);
} 

private void seuMetodo() {
    String nomeCliente = (String) cbNomeCliente.getSelectedItem();
    String nomeFuncionario = (String) cbNomeFuncionario.getSelectedItem();
    String nomeLivro = (String) cbNomeLivro.getSelectedItem();

    int idCliente, idFuncionario, idLivro;
    try (CamadaDeDados c = new CamadaDeDados(params())) {
        idCliente = c.clientes().porNome(nomeCliente).get(0).getId();
        idFuncionario = c.funcionarios().porNome(nomeFuncionario).get(0).getId();
        idLivro = c.livros().porNome(nomeLivro).get(0).getId();
    } catch (SQLException x) {
        JOPtionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x.getMessage());
    }
}
```

O ideal seria você utilizar o padrão de projeto MVC, de forma que a lógica de apresentação (que lida com `JComboBox`es e `JOptionPane`s) não ficasse presa à sua lógica de modelagem (que implementa as regras e os conceitos de livros, funcionários e clientes). Entretanto, eu precisaria de mais informações sobre o seu projeto para mostrar como fazer isso, e daí já seria o caso de fazer uma outra pergunta, pois isso está bem além do propósito dessa daqui.

Esses `get(0)` que tive que colocar provavelmente não são o ideal, sendo coisas indesejadas. Entretanto, para me livrar deles, eu precisaria ter mais informações sobre o seu projeto. Com esses `get(0)` o que fiz foi simplesmente assumir que sempre existirá um e apenas um resultado, mas isso é algo perigoso de se supor porque os métodos de listagem por nome podem trazer mais do que um resultado ou podem não trazer nenhum, o que significa que poderíamos não encontrar os `id`s procurados ou encontrar mais do que um `id`, e se isso daí acontecer, daí você vai ter que ver o que você vai fazer.

Em projetos profissionais bem feitos usando JDBC, você nunca ou quase nunca vai apenas pesquisar pelo id no banco de dados. Quase sempre você vai querer pegar a tupla inteira. É por isso que os métodos do DAO retornar `List<Cliente>` e `Optional<Cliente>` ao invés de apenas `int`. Por isso também desconfio que a sua abordagem de pesquisar pelo `id` não está correta.

Observe que se a `url`, o `usuario` e a `senha` forem fixos e imutáveis, você pode colocar o `ParametrosDeConexao` em uma variável `private static final` e reutilizar sempre a mesma instância.

Cada vez que você utilizar um objeto do tipo `CamadaDeDados` dentro do *try-with-resources*, você estará executando uma operação com o banco de dados em uma única conexão. Ela também é o lugar ideal para implementar controle de transações quando/se você precisar disso.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, além de me ajudar a resolver o problema ainda me deu umas dicas de boa prática. Valeu

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do @VictorStafusa é muito boa e bem completa, mas sendo um pouco mais direto... Você pode usar o [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

```
try{
   //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
   stm = conexao.createStatement();

   sqlChamaChaveCliente = "select idcliente from cliente where nome='" + nomeCliente +"'";

   ResultSet rsCliente = stm.executeQuery(sqlChamaChaveCliente);
   while(rsCliente.next()) {
        idcliente = rsCliente.getInt("idcliente");
   }
}
```

---

Agora sim, como mencionado na outra resposta, existem alguns pontos de atenção:

- Você precisa garantir que todos os recursos foram fechados: a Connection, o Statement e o ResultSet. Você pode fechá-los "na mão" ou usar o `try-with-resources` se estiver usando Java 7+
- O código dessa forma está totalmente passível de *SQL Injection*. Ao invés de usar `Statement`, use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).