# Métodos first() e next() não funcionam no ResultSet, mesmo editando os parâmetros

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

Preciso fazer duas iterações no mesmo `ResultSet`. Pra isso eu fiz o seguinte:

Setei parâmetros em um `Statement` para tornar o cursor editável, conforme o meu construtor da classe de conexão:

```
public ConexaoComDb(){


        try {

            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {

            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./lib/BDContaNoBB", "sa", "");

             stmt = cn.createStatement(
                     ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                     ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Depois eu faço um `while(resultSet.next())`. Depois disso, vem eu seto o `result` com o `first()`. Em um método seguinte eu tento iterar de novo com o `resultSet.next()`, mas ao invés de mostrar a tabela completa com o *print*, o que aparece é duas vezes a primeira linha, como se não houvesse havido iteração em nenhum dos dois `while`s.

Abaixo segue o código do método que realiza a query, gerando conteúdo para o `resultSet`, e o método que tem o primeiro `while (rs.next())`:

```
public void executaBusca(String nomeTable, String colunas, String condicao){


        try {


            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT " +colunas+ " FROM " +nomeTable+
                    " "+condicao);

            imprimeConsulta(rs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Primeiro `while (rs.next())`:

```
public void imprimeConsulta(ResultSet result){

        try {

            metaDadosDoRs = result.getMetaData();
            numeroColunas = metaDadosDoRs.getColumnCount();
            int greaterCel;

            for (int coluna=1; coluna<=numeroColunas; coluna++){
                greaterCel= tamanhoDaMaiorCelula(coluna);
                formatarCelulas(greaterCel, coluna);
            }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Segundo `while(rs.next())`:

```
public int tamanhoDaMaiorCelula(int coluna){

        int TamConteudoDaAtual=0;
        int TamConteudoDaAnterior=0;
        int indiceMaiorCel=0;
        int tamMaiorCel=0;
        String conteudo;



        try {


        while(rs.next()){           

            conteudo = rs.getString(coluna);


            TamConteudoDaAtual = conteudo.length();

                if (TamConteudoDaAtual > TamConteudoDaAnterior){
                    indiceMaiorCel = TamConteudoDaAtual;
                    tamMaiorCel = TamConteudoDaAtual;
                 }

            TamConteudoDaAnterior = TamConteudoDaAtual;

        }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            formatarCelulas(tamMaiorCel, coluna);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tamMaiorCel;
        }
```

E finalmente, o método que imprime a tabela formatada. Que era pra imprimir toda ela, que possui 5 linhas, mas só imprime duas vezes o conteúdo da primeira linha...

```
public void formatarCelulas(int tamMaiorCel, int coluna) throws SQLException{

        rs.first();

        ArrayList<String> stringFormatada = new ArrayList<String>();

        do {

                int tamQueFalta = rs.getString(coluna).length() - tamMaiorCel;
                char[] arrayDoTamQueFalta = new char[tamQueFalta];

                String tamLast = new String (arrayDoTamQueFalta);

                stringFormatada.add(rs.getString(coluna));
                stringFormatada.add(tamLast);

                System.out.println(stringFormatada.toString());

                stringFormatada.clear();

            }while(rs.next());

        }
```

Comment: Você poderia postar a classe `ConexaoComDb` inteira, para ficar mais fácil de analisar e alterar o código? Além disso, em que contexto você usa o método `executaBusca` e com quais parâmetros? Estou redigindo uma resposta e o seu código têm vários problemas, mas se você me der essas informações, eu consigo elaborar uma resposta mais precisa e detalhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Não armazene os `Statement`s e `ResultSet`s em variáveis de instância sem ter um motivo muito forte para fazer isso. Esta forma que você está usando faz com que eles fiquem muito mais difíceis de serem adequadamente gerenciados e muito mais fácil de se fazer besteiras com eles.
2. Embora você possa ler um `ResultSet` mais do que uma vez, isso não costuma ser uma boa ideia. O ideal é que você o leia apenas uma vez e monte na memória uma estrutura que corresponde ao que você leu (não necessariamente em um mapeamento 1-para-1, você pode fazer otimizações, simplificações e totalizações enquanto lê o `ResultSet`). No seu caso você está *tentando* percorrer **duas vezes para cada coluna** só para determinar o tamanho da maior string na primeira e ler o dado na segunda. Isso é terrivelmente ineficiente, pois o ideal é minimizar o tráfego de dados com o banco de dados (mesmo que seja o H2 em memória) e portanto você só deveria percorrer o `ResultSet` uma, e somente uma vez para cumprir o propósito do método `executaBusca`.
3. Evite formar SQLs ao concatenar pedaços de Strings. Fazer isso é pedir para ter problemas de segurança com [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL), e por esse motivo é considerado uma péssima prática de programação.
4. **NUNCA** faça isso:

   ```
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```

   Isso daí é pedir para o seu programa ter erros misteriosos e difíceis de rastrear. É tentar prosseguir em fazer algo que já se sabe que deu errado como se tivesse dado certo.
5. Isso daqui não deve mais ser necessário:

   ```
       try {

           Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```

   Veja mais sobre isso [nessa outra questão minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242765/132).
6. Gerenciar os seus recursos fica muito mais fácil ao utilizar-se o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132). No seu caso você não está gerenciando-os adequadamente e nem mesmo com algo que seria próximo do adequado.
7. Não coloque o modificador `public` em métodos internos. O método disponibilizado para ser usado externamente é o `executaBusca`. Os demais métodos são funcionalidades internas do `executaBusca` que não deveriam ser disponibilizadas para outras classes usarem.
8. A forma como você faz para tentar formatar uma coluna não funciona. Para demonstrar o porquê, veja esse código:

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   class VaiDarErrado {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String a = "batata";
           char[] teste = new char[123];
           String s = new String(teste);
           List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
           lista.add(a);
           lista.add(s);
           System.out.println(lista.toString());
       }
   }
   ```

   Eis a saída:

   ```
   [batata, ]
   ```

   [**Veja o resultado no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/czcaYa)

   Ou seja, todo o cálculo de tamanho de coluna e de espaços a serem preenchidos é em vão porque o tamanho do `char[]` passado ao construtor de `String` é irrelevante e o que importa nele é quais posições estão preenchidas, que não é nenhuma no seu caso. Além disso não é boa ideia usar `ArrayList` para concatenar ou formatar `Strings`. [Use o **`StringBuilder`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) ou então o [método **`format(String, Object...)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) para isso. O fato de você estar usando `System.out.println` significa que você quebra linhas após cada dado, e portanto o alinhamento dos espaços extras seria irrelevante. Por fim, mesmo se você arrumar essa questão dos espaços extras e quebras de linha, vai dar errado porque você vai mostrar os dados agrupados por coluna, e não por linha. Ou seja, essa parte está completamente errada e tem que ser refeita do zero.
9. Usar `System.out.println` como saída dos dados é algo muito ruim. Isso torna esse método quase impossível de ser reutilizado em um ambiente onde a ideia seria colocar os resultados em uma tela ou então em uma tabela HTML ou coisa assim sem que o código tenha que sofrer significativas alterações. E se o código está numa situação onde ele precisaria sofrer significativas alterações para ser reutilizado, então significa que não é um código bom.
10. Evite utilizar variáveis com tipos que sejam implementações de interfaces tais como `ArrayList` e lembre-se da sintaxe do diamante ao usar genéricos. Por exemplo, ao invés disso:

    ```
    ArrayList<String> stringFormatada = new ArrayList<String>();
    ```

    Use isso:

    ```
    List<String> stringFormatada = new ArrayList<>();
    ```

    Observe que embora o construtor chamado ainda seja o de `ArrayList`, o tipo da variável é `List` simplesmente. Isso torna-se bastante importante quando você tem parâmetros do tipo `ArrayList` ou métodos que retornam `ArrayList`. Quando você usa apenas `List`, você elimina vários problemas de interoperabiliade que resultariam quando você tiver que interagir com outros tipos de listas.

Bem, agora que enumerei os problemas, vamos começar criando uma classe para representar uma linha da tabela:

```
import java.util.List;

public final class Linha {
     private final List<String> dados;

     public Linha(List<String> dados) {
         this.dados = dados;
     }

     public void computarTamanho(int[] tamanhosColunas) {
         if (tamanhosColunas.length != dados.size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         for (int i = 0; i < tamanhosColunas.length; i++) {
             String dado = dados.get(i);
             if (dado == null) dado = "<null>";
             int t = dado.length();
             if (t > tamanhosColunas[i]) tamanhosColunas[i] = t;
         }
     }

     public void formatar(StringBuilder sb, int[] tamanhosColunas) {
         if (tamanhosColunas.length != dados.size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         for (int i = 0; i < tamanhosColunas.length; i++) {
             if (i != 0) sb.append(' ');
             String dado = dados.get(i);
             if (dado == null) dado = "<null>";
             sb.append(dado);
             for (int j = dado.length(); j < tamanhosColunas[i]; j++) {
                 sb.append(' ');
             }
         }
         sb.append('\n');
     }
}
```

Agora uma classe para representar a tabela de resultados:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class Tabela {
     private final List<Linha> linhas;
     private final int[] tamanhosColunas;

     public Tabela(int qtdColunas, List<List<String>> listao) {
         this.tamanhosColunas = new int[qtdColunas];
         this.linhas = new ArrayList<>();

         for (List<String> listinha : listao) {
             Linha proxima = new Linha(listinha);
             linhas.add(proxima);
             proxima.computarTamanho(tamanhosColunas);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for (Linha lin : linhas) {
             lin.formatar(sb, tamanhosColunas);
         }
         return sb.toString();
     }
}
```

E então, vamos construir uma instância de `Tabela` a partir do banco de dados:

Aqui vai a sugestão de como poderia ser a sua classe que conecta com o banco de dados:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class TabelaDoBd {

    private static Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./lib/BDContaNoBB", "sa", "");
    }

    public static Tabela executarBusca(String sql) throws SQLException {
        try (
            Connection con = conectar();
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        )
        {
            ResultSetMetaData metaDadosDoRs = rs.getMetaData();
            int numeroColunas = metaDadosDoRs.getColumnCount();

            List<List<String>> listao = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                List<String> listinha = new ArrayList<>(numeroColunas);
                for (int i = 1; i <= numeroColunas; i++) {
                    listinha.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                listao.add(listinha);
            }
            return new Tabela(numeroColunas, listao);
        }
    }
}
```

Esses códigos acima resolvem todos os problemas que enumerei, mas acaba delegando a montagem da SQL para fora. Esse detalhe da SQL vir de fora pode ser resolvido se você me dizer sob que circunstâncias você usa ou espera usar o método `executarBusca`. Para usar esse código, faça assim:

```
Tabela t = TabelaDoBd.executarBusca("SELECT ID, NOME, TELEFONE FROM CLIENTES");
System.out.println(t);
```

Você pode acrescentar outros métodos em `Tabela` e `Linha` se quiser para fazer outras operações com os dados lidos. Observe que eu os fiz imutáveis pelos motivos que explico [**nessa outra resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132).

Comment: :O Impressionante. Vou começar arrumar tudo. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Provavelmente essas buscas vão vir de fora da classe mesmo. Minha ideia é que este lado da aplicação que eu estou fazendo seja um servidor. As requisição de querys vão vir de uma aplicação cliente web, que eu ainda nem sei como fazer. kkk. Mas esse é o objetivo deste meu pequeno projeto, aprender a integrar banco de dados com aplicações java, depois aprender a construir aplicações web e comunicá-las com um servidor...

Comment: Como nessa aplicação,as consultas ao banco de dados serão frequentes, não seria mais adequado criar essa classe de conexão com o BD como um Singleton que mantém-se aberto durante toda a operação da aplicação?  Você disse que dá menos confusão criar o objeto connection de forma local, mas não é custoso de mais, ficar criando e destruindo a conexão toda hora?

Comment: @LucasPletsch Sim é. Ocorre que para quem está num nível inicial, eu recomendo fazer assim para evitar fazer besteira. Num nível intermediário, pode guardar o objeto da conexão e montar com ele um escopo de transação (tal como fiz [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258256/132)). Num nível mais avançado (que é o que faço em meus projetos), eu mantenho a conexão aberta e quando vou fazer uma operação nela, verifico se ela não acabou sendo fechada espontaneamente (ex: inatividade durante a madrugada) e se tiver sido, reabro tudo de forma transparente para o método que for utilizá-la.

Comment: Suspeitei desde o princípio. kkk

Comment: Outra pergunta: se eu vou apresentar esses resultados em html, por exemplo, eu preciso fazer toda essa formatação da tabela em java? Ou posso retornar somente o resultSet e as questões de exibição da tabela são tratadas no front-end, com html por exemplo...?

Comment: @LucasPletsch Há várias formas de sse fazer isso. Você pode montar o HTML no Java, você pode usar JSP, pode usar JSF, pode usar uma ferramenta de templating (velocity, mustache, thymeleaf, freemarker, etc), pode formatar como XML, JSON ou outra coisa e montar o HTML no Javascript com jQuery, enfim, há muitas formas, e possivelmente você pode precisar usar mais do que uma delas. Seja como for o caminho, se você não estiver usando Jackson, GSON, JAXB ou outra coisa que gere JSON/XML direto a partir do objeto, o melhor é acrescentar métodos específicos em `Linha` e `Tabela` para isso.

Comment: @LucasPletsch No entanto, a regra aqui é não deixar o `ResultSet` aberto. Primeiro você lê tudo do banco de dados e constrói um objeto em memória que representa isso tudo que você leu, e só depois você faz alguma coisa com esse objeto. A exceção seria se o que você estiver carregando do banco de dados for algo que tenha vários megabytes ou gigabytes merecendo ser tratado e consumido enquanto o `ResultSet` ainda estiver aberto, mas isso é bem mais difícil e trabalhoso de se fazer corretamente e como o seu caso é simples, é melhor deixar para quando você estiver bem mais experiente com o Java.

Comment: Não entendi porque no segundo for do método "formatar" da classe linha, você acrescenta espaços pra ajustar a largura da célula. Esta célula já não tem o tamanho do conteúdo contido nela, + o espaço inicial? Uma vez que o array tamanhosColunas[i] contém o tamanho individual de cada célula, que é setado de acordo com o tamanho do conteúdo contido nela (tamanhosolunas[i] = t, no método computarTamanho()), dado.length e tamanhosColunas[i] não teriam o mesmo valor?

Comment: @LucasPletsch As strings do campo `dados` da classe `Linha` não têm os espaços adicionais, eles são acrescentados justamente no método `formatar`. O segundo `for` é para preencher os espaços faltantes. O espaço acrescido no `if` é para separar uma coluna da outra. O método `computarTamanho` só calcula os tamanhos, ele não acrescenta espaços em nenhuma string (esses ssão acrescentados só no método `formatar`). Dessa forma, `dado.length()` e `tamanhosColunas[i]` vão normalmente ser valores diferentes.

Comment: Essa historia de se delegar a montagem de SQL pra fora: você quer dizer: minha aplicação já recebe a string com o SQL pronta?

Comment: Sobre o ponto 4, você poderia colocar a famosa frase: toda exceção costurada sem ser corretamente tratada [mata uma fada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21989/64969)