# Retornar dados do BD usando List/ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql, jdbc

Estou com um problema, montei uma tabela dinâmica no PostgreSQL e preciso imprimir as linhas da mesma, realizando um método em Java, cujo início já está pré-estabelecido. Que seria com um `List` simples tendo como parâmetro as datas de início e fim.

Segue o código pré-estabelecido:

```
public void printReport(Date initialDate, Date endDate) {
          List<Sale> sales = getSales(initialDate, endDate);
          ...
}
```

A saída precisa ser por exemplo: `Loja01;100;100;50;0;250`.
Porém não sei como acessar a coluna e a linha da loja passando por todos os dados.

Eu ja tenho um metodo que imprime da seguinte forma. Exemplo: Loja01 com 3 vendas (100,00 visa; 55,00 visa; 200,00 master) ira imprimir: 
Loja01; visa; 155 // na outra linha
Loja01;master;200;
Segue codigo em java:

```
    public void printReport (Date initialDate, Date endDate){

        List<Sale> sales = getSales (initialDate, endDate);

        for (Sale s:sales){

            Store st = s.getStore(); // Recupera a Loja

            CreditCard cc = s.getCreditCard(); // Recupera o Cartão

            System.out.println(st.getNome() + ";" + cc.getName() + ";" + s.getValor());
        }
}
```

[image: Imagem dos registros da tabela]

[image: Tabelas criados no BD]

Comment: Leitura recomendada 1: [**Como funciona o try-with-resources?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132)

Comment: Leitura recomendada 2: [**Erro ao armazenar dados de um Select com Java**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258256/132)

Comment: Leitura recomendada 3: [**Como migrar de Date e Calendar para a nova API de datas no Java 8?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, iniciamos com uma classe que representa uma venda. Essa classe é imutável, veja os motivos [**nessa outra resposta minha**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132):

```
public final class Sale {
    private final String storeNome;
    private final int visa;
    private final int master;
    private final int diners;
    private final int amex;

    public Sale(String storeName, int visa, int mster, int diners, int amex) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
        this.visa = visa;
        this.master = master;
        this.diners = diners;
        this.amex = amex;
    }

    public String getStoreNome() {
        return storeNome;
    }

    public int getVisa() {
        return visa;
    }

    public int getMaster() {
        return master;
    }

    public int getDiners() {
        return diners;
    }

    public int getAmex() {
        return amex;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return visa + master + diners + amex;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return storeNome + ";"
                + visa + ";" + master + ";" + diners + ";" + amex + ";" + getTotal();
    }
}
```

Feito isso, vou pegar emprestado [**dessa outra resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258256/132) uma classe que representa parâmetro de conexão:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ParametrosDeConexao {

    private final String url;
    private final String usuario;
    private final String senha;

    public BaseDeDados(String url, String usuario, String senha) {
        this.url = url;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
    }
}
```

Você vai ter que criar uma instância desta classe e mantê-la em algum lugar (pode ser uma variável estática) para poder conectar no banco de dados. A definição da URL, do usuário e da senha dependerá de qual será o seu banco de dados.

Por fim, podemos fazer a classe que acessa o banco de dados:

```
public class SaleDAO {

    private static final String SALES_BY_DATES_SQL = ""
            + "SELECT store_nome, visa, master, diners, amex "
            + "FROM Sale "
            + "WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ?";

    private final ParametrosDeConexao params;

    public SaleDAO(ParametrosDeConexao params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public List<Sale> getSales(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        try (
            Connection c = params.conectar();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(SALES_BY_DATES_SQL);
        )
        {
            ps.setDate(1, startDate);
            ps.setDate(2, endDate);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                List<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<>();
                while (rs.hasNext()) {
                    Sale s = new Sale(
                            rs.getString("store_nome"),
                            rs.getInt("visa"),
                            rs.getInt("master"),
                            rs.getInt("diners"),
                            rs.getInt("amex"));
                    sales.add(s);
                }
                return sales;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima se preocupa em [fechar os recursos adequadamente com a ajuda do compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

O código acima presume que o `Date` contenha também a informação das horas. Portanto se você colocar que o `endDate` for no dia 10/10/2018 00:00:00, ele não pegará a venda feita às 09:00 do dia 10/10/2018. Se não deseja esse comportamento, deixe um comentário aqui nessa resposta. Uma alternativa para isso seria [trabalhar com a classe `LocalDate` ou `LocalDateTime`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132).

Observe que omiti o campo `total` na SQL e na classe `Sale`. O motivo é que ele sempre é a soma de `visa`, `master`, `diners` e `amex`, e portanto não precisaria ser lido do banco de dados e nem armazenado em memória. Se for realmente esse o caso, você poderia até removê-lo da tabela.

Comment: Entao,  li sua sugestões e realmente absorvi mais conhecimentos.Só estou em duvida quanto aos atributos da classe sale, eu nao posso pegar o identificador de cada cartao e loja do proprio insert do Banco?
Vou editar a pergunta e colocar as minhas tabelas.

Comment: @LucasEsbegue Qual SELECT você montou juntando as tabelas `Sale`, `CreditCard` e `Store`? Em especial, quero entender de onde vieram os campos `visa`, `master`, `diners` e `amex` bem como os respectivos valores.

Comment: Segue link do BD no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5c3eb/1.
Montei um select que usa uma função do postgresql, o 'jsonb_object_agg', tentei fazer com o crosstab, porem nao consegui.Bem os campos vieram do proprio insert em suas respectivas tabelas.

Comment: Alguma sugestão? Nao sei como utilizar as tres tabelas no java.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<Sale> getSales (Date startDate, Date endDate  ){

        Conection con = //de alguma forma vc pega conexao com o banco

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

         List<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<>();

        //aqui você recebe um objeto ResultSet com todos os elementos
        //da tabela ales:

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sales s WHERE  s.date BETWEEN ? AND ? ");

           stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date( startDate.getTime() )) ;
           stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime() ));

        //para percorrer o resultset, faca:

        while(rs.next()) {

           Sale sale = new Sale();

          //pega o valor da coluna nome, de cada linha:
          sale.setStoreName ( rs.getString("store_nome") ) ;
          sale.setVisa( rs.getString("visa") );
          sale.setMaster( rs.getString("master") ) ;
          sale.setDiners ( rs.getString("diners") );
          sale.setAmex ( rs.getString("amex") );
          sale.setTotal ( rs.getDouble("total") );

          sales.add(sale);

    }

   return  sales;

 }// end getSales
```

**CLASS**

```
public class  Sale {

         //por questões didáticas coloquei como String a maioria.

          private String storeName;
          private String visa ;
          private String master ;
          private String diners;
          private String amex ;
          private Double total;


     //getts e setts

}
```

**MÉTODO:**

```
public void printReport(Date initialDate, Date endDate) {
          List<Sale> sales = getSales(initialDate, endDate);//chamando getSales
          ...
}
```

Comment: Leitura recomendada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132

Comment: @LR10, eu uso tres tabelas no BD e preciso criar as sua respectivas classe no java, nao apenas colocar tudo na sale.
Eu preciso apenas codificar o meto printReport, com um print simples, porem nao sei a forma de acessar as informações.

Comment: então vc tem que fazer um VO com os campos  que vc quer que apareça no relatoria e depois fazer um SQL que retornar os dados deseja e popular ele no seu VO.

Comment: @LR10 Entao, a minha tarefa é apenas montar o metodo, levando em consideração que todas as classes (Sale, Store, Credit_Card, as de acesso ao banco etc...ja estejam prontas, eu preciso criar o metodo para printar conforme coloquei na pergunta. Nunca vi VO, vou da uma pesquisada

Comment: Vc que um método que imprima se relatório?

Comment: Isso @LR10, so a continuação que complete o metodo printReport. Levando em consideração o meu BD. E levando em consideração que todo o resto do programa esteja perfeito.

Comment: Eu tenho um metodo que imprime da seguinte forma: 
Exemplo: Loja01 com 3 vendas(100,00 visa; 55,00 visa; 200,00 master) irá aparecer no relatorio assim: 
Loja01;visa;155;
Loja01;Master; 200;
Editei a pergunta e adicionei o metodo que imprime dessa forma.

Comment: @LucasEsbegue essa edicao que fez é outro problema?

Comment: Nao @Articuno, o metodo funciona. So editei pra informar o que eu tenho no momento, e o que eu estou tentando fazer. Que é imprimir por exemplo:Loja01;100;100;50;0;250. Levando em conta a foto da tabela que postei na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir os dados separados por `;`, considerando a busca dos dados do banco de dados feito pelo colega ai em cima
Depois que voce buscou os dados do seu banco de dados ou outro, E tem os dados em uma coleção no java(ArrayList), é só iterar o array assim:

```
      public void printReport(Date initialDate, Date endDate) {
        List<Sale> sales = getSales(initialDate, endDate);//chamando getSales
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Sales sale: sales){
        sb.append(sale.getStoreName() + ";" + sale.getVisa() + ";"+sale.getMaster() + ";" + sale.getDiners() + ";" + sale.getAmex() + ";" + sale.getTotal());


    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

pode ficar mais fácil ainda se voce sobrescrever o metodo toString da classe Sales

```
 @override
 public String toString(){
  return storeName+";"+visa+";"+master+";"+dinners+";"+amex+";"+total;
 }
```

Então no for voce faria:

```
for(Sales sale: sales){
   sb.append(sale.toString());


  }
```

**Edit: Considerar o objeto Store como atributo da classe Sale (Trechos de código de outras respostas nessa pergunta)**

Classe Store.

```
public class Store{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //gets and sets
}
```

Classe Sale

```
public class  Sale {

     //por questões didáticas coloquei como String a maioria.

      private Store store;
      private String visa ;
      private String master ;
      private String diners;
      private String amex ;
      private Double total;


 //getts e setts
 }
```

Um exemplo do Select que traria os dados do BD

```
private static final String SALES_BY_DATES_SQL = ""
        + "SELECT store.name store_name, store.id store_id, visa, master, diners, amex "
        + "FROM Sale, Store "
        + "WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ?"
        + " and sale.store_id = store.id";
```

Método que recupera dados do BD

```
public List<Sale> getSales(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    try (
        Connection c = params.conectar();
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(SALES_BY_DATES_SQL);
    )
    {
        ps.setDate(1, startDate);
        ps.setDate(2, endDate);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            List<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                Sale s = new Sale(
                        //carregando o objeto store.
                        Store store = new Store();
                        store.setId(rs.getInt("store_id"));
                        store.setName(rs.getString("store_name"));
                        sale.setStore(store);

                        rs.getInt("visa"),
                        rs.getInt("master"),
                        rs.getInt("diners"),
                        rs.getInt("amex"));
                sales.add(s);
            }
            return sales;
        }
    }
}
```

Depois pra criar o layout:

```
for(Sales sale: sales){
        sb.append(sale.getStore().getName() + ";" + sale.getVisa() + ";"+sale.getMaster() + ";" + sale.getDiners() + ";" + sale.getAmex() + ";" + sale.getTotal());


}
```

ou:

```
 @override
 public String toString(){
  return getStore().getName()+";"+visa+";"+master+";"+dinners+";"+amex+";"+total;
 }
```

**Edit: Considerando que os dados já estão vindo certos do banco de dados:**

método que formata a impressão:

```
public StringBuilder formatarLayout(ArrayList<Sales> sales){
StirngBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Sales sale: sales){
        sb.append(sale.getStore().getName() + ";" + sale.getVisa() + ";"+sale.getMaster() + ";" + sale.getDiners() + ";" + sale.getAmex() + ";" + sale.getTotal());


    }

    return sb;

}
```

método printReport

```
public void printReport(Date initialDate, Date endDate) {
          List<Sale> sales = getSales(initialDate, endDate);
          //isso ja retorna seus dados formatados
          String  layout = formatarLayout(sales).toString();
          // agora pode fazer o que quiser com eles
}
```

Comment: Sim, isso realmente foi o mais proximo que estou tentando buscar.Porem o "storeName" não faz parte da tabela Sale qie passando para o java seriam as classes. Esse é o meu maior problema e duvida, a unica relaçao que eles tem sao os id's.Editei a pergunta e adicionei as tabelas e relações.

Comment: Cria dentro da classe Sales objeto Store, que contém o id e name.
No seu select, que retorna os dados do banco de dados, traga a informação das stores, fazendo o join por Id. No método que coloca isso no arrayList, carrega o objeto Store, que é um atributo da classe Sale
Depois, use normalmente no exemplo que dei, `sale.getStore().getName()`

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.Mas assim eu poderia utilizar o codigo ja pre-estabelecido? E eu nao estou entendendo pq preciso declarar como atributo os nomes dos cartões.

Comment: então, os atributos é pra voce poder recuperar os dados do banco de dados e poder usa-los no java,  como voce postou na sua pergunta: `Loja01;100;100;50;0;250` os valores `100, 100 50` são valores gurdados na coluna do visa, master diner

Comment: Ok, entendi!!! Mas com isso eu nao poderia mais utilizar o metodo --  'public void printReport(Date initialDate, Date endDate) {  
          List<Sale> sales = getSales(initialDate, endDate);
          ...
}
E o restante do seu for para imprimir os dados?

Comment: sim sim, na resposta, coloquei isso dentro do método printReport

Comment: Caso eu nao queira usar o metodo formatarLayout, posso usar o que ja tenho pre-estabelecido do metodo printReport e fazer a instacia do stringBuilder e o for, e depois imprimir com o System.out.println(sb.toString());?
Estaria correto?

Comment: sim, criei um método de exemplo só, voce pode usar como voce achar melhor no seu ambiente

Comment: Sim, compreendi.Uma outra duvida, nesse exemplo eu utilizaria a classe Credit_Card? Sendo que nessa tabela no BD estao os nomes dos cartões(visa, master, diners, amex).