# Inserindo dados no banco de dados atraves de PHP OO

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma classe que faz algumas funções para inserir e buscar informações dentro do banco de dados, ja fiz a conexão, porém não sei como tratar esse form, passar a classe na action do form?

Segue minha classe:

```
<?php

require_once "bcrypt.class.php";
require_once "db.class.php";
require_once "helpers.class.php";

/**
 *
 */
class DocModel
{

  protected static $Helpers;
  protected static $pdo;

  function __construct(argument)
  {
    self::$Helpers = new Helpers;
    self::$pdo = Database::connect();
  }

  public function addDoc($title, $text){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO doc_model (id, title, text) VALUES (DEFAULT, :title, :text);";
    $st = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $st->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $st->bindParam(':text', $text);
    $st->execute();

    if ($st->rowCount() > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public function getDoc(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM doc_model ORDER BY id DESC;";
    $st = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute();
    if ($docmodel = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      return $docmodel;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // public function removeDoc($title, $text){
  //   $sql = "DELETE FROM doc_model where "
  //
  // }
}
```

Segue meu formulario HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="?">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título *</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input name="title" type="text" class="validate[required] form-control" placeholder = "Título do documento modelo" value="<?php echo ((isset($array['title']))?$array['title']:"")?>"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Texto *</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder = "Texto da mensagem" ><?php echo ((isset($array['message']))?$array['message']:"")?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Salvar</button>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="tab" value="tab_1">
                        </form>
```

Quero salvar os dados desse form no bd, porém não sei onde receber os $_POST, se seria na classe ou em uma action.

Script intermediário:

```
<?php
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

define('__ROOT__', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once (__ROOT__.'/classes/user.class.php');
require_once (__ROOT__.'/classes/helpers.class.php');
require_once (__ROOT__.'/config.php');
require_once (__ROOT__.'/classes/docmodel.class.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['USER']) OR !User::checkSession($_SESSION['USER'])) {
    header ('Location: sair');
    exit;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['USER']['type']) AND $_SESSION['USER']['type'] > 2) {
    header ('Location: painel');
    exit;
}

$config['page-title'] = 'Documentos Modelo';

$User = new User;
$Helpers = new Helpers;
$DocModel = new DocModel();


$title = $_POST['title'];
$text = $_POST['message'];

var_dump($title, $text);exit();

$DocModel->addDoc($title, $text);


include_once ('templates/header.tpl.php');
include_once ('templates/sidebar.tpl.php');
include_once ('templates/breadcrumb.tpl.php');
include_once ('templates/modelos.tpl.php');
include_once ('templates/footer.tpl.php');
```

Comment: Crie um arquivo php `intermediario` por exemplo `exemplo.php` e coloque esse mesmo nome no action do seu `form`

Comment: ai nesse arquivo você captura o conteudo que vem  do formulário e os armazena em uma variável usando o $_POST

Comment: Geralmente essa classe que criou apenas interage com o banco, o melhor é criar outro arquivo que receba os dados, valide e então passe para a classe `DocModel`. De uma olhada no [padrão DAO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113840)

Comment: Recomendo utilizar `MVC`. O post seria enviado da `view`, seria recebido e tratado no `controller` e só depois passado para o `model`.

Answer (score 0):

Vou te dar uma base do que pode ser feito.

Crie um aquivo intermediário , por exemplo `meuexemplo.php`

```
<?php
//inclui o arquivo da sua classe
require_once "DocModel.php";

//Nesse arquivo você recebe o conteúdo vindo do formulário  
$aux = $_POST['campox'];

//para acessar a sua classe basta você criar o objeto da mesma
$model = new DocModel(); //Aqui não estou considerando que você esteja carregando as variáveis no construtor 

//a partir daqui vc pode acessar os métodos da sua classe com a variável $model 
 $model -> metodox($campox); //campox é o dado que vem do seu formulário
```

Comment: eu fiz isso, porem ta dando esse erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in ... on line 16

Comment: você usou esse exemplo que te passei? senão anexe o arquivo que você montou  na pergunta assim a gente pode verificar qual pode ser o problema.

Comment: Desculpa, ele deu foi esse erro: Notice: Undefined index: title in

Comment: coloque esse código na pergunta , só com erro não da para definir o problema

Comment: Coloquei la Thiago

Comment: Vamos debugar esse código então , ele chega a executar o `var_dump()`?

Answer (score 0):

para o form, dê um name e um action
**o objeto form vai ficar assim:**

```
<form method="post" name="NomeDoFORM" action="ArquivoInserir.php">    
</form>
```

o php não sabe o que é um **'id='** o php entende o **'name='**
a menos que você queira usar JS. esqueça o id no no momento. Para nao dificutar vou fazer a explicação bem mastigadinha. pra voce adaptar.
os items como vão:

```
<seletor name="NomeDoCampo1" />
<seletor name="NomeDoCampo2" />
```

agora o form tem uma cara nova para o php.

```
<form method="post" name="NomeDoFORM" action="ArquivoInserir.php"> 
    <seletor name="NomeDoCampo1" />
    <seletor name="NomeDoCampo2" />   
</form>
```

agora vamos fazer o processamento do formulario.
supondo que você ja sabe a linguagem do banco... vou fazer resumido.

> ArquivoInserir.php

```
<?php
//crie uma variavel para cada campo
$variavelParaCampo1=$_POST['NomeDoCampo1'];
$variavelParaCampo2=$_POST['NomeDoCampo2'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO NomeDaTabela (NomeDaColuna1,NomeDaColuna2) VALUES ('$variavelParaCampo1','$variavelParaCampo2')";
// ou então:
$sql = "INSERT INTO NomeDaTabela (NomeDaColuna1,NomeDaColuna2) VALUES ('$_POST['NomeDoCampo1']','$_POST['NomeDoCampo1']')";
?>
```

Se quiser enviar com Jquery, você pode escolher o campo por id, ou então enviar o formulario todo de uma vez. MANDA UM GRITO AI. marca que resolveu.