# Como separar o HTML do código Java de conexão com o banco?

Tags: java, html, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados e um código html que finalmente consegui fazer conexão mas o código esta meio bagunçado pois mistura html com java e mysql... Segue exemplo:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*" %>    

<%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cadastro", "root","");
    String acao = request.getParameter("acao");
    if(acao == null){
        acao="listarPessoas";
    }

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>cadastro</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="#" method="post">

        <%

            if(acao.equals("cadastro")){
                String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
                String idade = request.getParameter("idade");
                if(nome != null && idade != null){
                    String sql="INSERT INTO pessoa(nome,idade) VALUE(?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    stmt.setString(1, nome);
                    stmt.setString(2, idade);
                    stmt.execute();
                    out.println("pessoa" + " "+ nome + " " +idade );

                    acao="listarPessoas";

                    acao="novoCadastroPessoas";
                    out.println("<v> TODOS OS CAMPOS DEVER SER PREENCHIDOS</v>");
                }else{
                    acao="novoCadastroPessoas";
                    out.println("<v> TODOS OS CAMPOS DEVER SER PREENCHIDOS</v>");
                }
            }







            if(acao.equals("novoCadastro")){


        %>

        <label for="nome">nome:</label>
        <input type = "text " name="nome">
        <label for="idade">idade:</label>
        <input type="date" id="idade">
        <button type="submite" name="acao" value="listarPessoas">voltar</button>
        <button type="submite" name="acao" value="cadastro">salvar</button>

        <%
            }else if(acao.equals("listarPessoas")){
        %>

        <button type="submit" name="acao" value="novoCadastro">Novo cadastro</button>
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Data de nascimento</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
                <tr>
                    <tb></tb>
                    <tb></tb>
                    <tb></tb>
                </tr>   

        <fieldset>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Como posso fazer com que o html e o java não se misturem, criando classes para funções tipo conectar ao banco de dados ou para extrair informações? E onde colocar as funções no código?

Comment: Estude sobre Java Server Pages (JSP) e server-side rendering.

Comment: Não notei que já estava usando uma JSP. Convém estudar sobre taglibs/JSTL. Experimente com essa apostila da Caelum (está meio defasada em relação à época que foi lançada, mas é bem didática): https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/javaserver-pages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso queira fazer uma divisão bacana eu recomendo estudar sobre o padrão **DAO (Data Access Object)**

[Sobre DAO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113840/como-funciona-o-padr%C3%A3o-dao)

Posteriormente sobre **MVC (Model View Controller)**, para esse recomendo estudar um pouco mais sobre:

**HTTP:** Para entender mais sobre requisição e resposta (request and response) e como é utilizado o principal protocolo web. 
**SERVLET:** Esse é a base da maioria (se não de todos) os frameworks MVC Java, entender como ele funciona vai ser fundamental.

[Sobre MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Obs: Os dois padrões mencionados permitem que você faça uma separação quase completa do backend e do frontend, tem mais opções boas como por exemplo o [Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305199/repository-pattern-how-to-understand-it-and-how-does-it-work-with-complex-en) mas o DAO e o MVC acredito que sejam a porta de entrada para um projeto web bem dividido.

Comment: vlw bro, ajudo muito kkk